# Typescript - Compiling dependent js files

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having issues with the typescript compiler and external js libraries that use corresponding `.d.ts` definition files.

The issue is that these have to be referenced in the html code. With many nested libraries this is becoming an issue that I'm not sure how to solve this.

E.g.
I have my external modules like so:

1. Module 1 (js) - no dependencies
2. Module 2 (ts) - depends on Module 1
3. Module 3 (ts) - depends on Module 2
4. Application (ts) - depends on Module 3

In my html, because Module 1 is JavaScript, even though it has a definition file, I have to add:

```html
<script src="Module1.min.js"></script>
```

Is there anyway round this as this is easily shooting up to 50+ `script` tags that need to be swapped out on a regular basis as dependencies change within the modules.

Comment: What compile flag for `--module` are you using?

Comment: At the moment i'm just using the internal module system

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at System.js, it will load any required modules for you

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what i'm looking for. Looks like it takes even more leg work than just adding the <script> tags.

I'm looking for the external js libraries to be compiled within the module depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway round this as this is easily shooting up to 50+ script tags that need to be swapped out on a regular basis as dependencies change within the modules.

Use an external module system. Managing them manually is a nightmare : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md

Recommend you just use `--module commonjs` with http://webpack.github.io/